# How to set the day number of a date to any random number from 1-30 in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, date, pandas

Hello I have a dateSting containging date say 2017-10

Now i m passing this date to 
`dateparse = lambda dates: pandas.datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y-%m')`
this function
and it will return 2017-10-01 as a date type but now i want to have any random number from 0-31 instead of 01 in that date how can i achive this

And In an array how to swap the column data for all the rows ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.randrange()` to add the day number to your datetime:

```
In [22]: from random import randrange
In [23]: import pandas as pd

In [24]: dateparse = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date + '-{}'.format(randrange(1,31)), '%Y-%m-%d')

In [25]: dateparse('2017-10')
Out[25]: datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 27, 0, 0)

In [26]: dateparse('2017-10')
Out[26]: datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 17, 0, 0)

In [27]: dateparse('2017-10')
Out[27]: datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [21]: def random_dt(s):
    ...:     d = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y-%m')
    ...:     return d + pd.DateOffset(days=random.randint(0, d.daysinmonth-1))
    ...:

In [22]: random_dt('2017-10')
Out[22]: Timestamp('2017-10-31 00:00:00')

In [23]: random_dt('2017-10')
Out[23]: Timestamp('2017-10-19 00:00:00')

In [24]: random_dt('2017-10')
Out[24]: Timestamp('2017-10-24 00:00:00')

In [25]: random_dt('2017-10')
Out[25]: Timestamp('2017-10-12 00:00:00')
```

**UPDATE:** [new feauture in Pandas 0.20.1:](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#to-datetime-has-gained-an-origin-parameter)

> `to_datetime()` has gained a new parameter, `origin`, to define a
>   reference date from where to compute the resulting timestamps when
>   parsing numerical values with a specific unit specified. (GH11276,
>   GH11745)

```
def random_dt(s, periods=1, format='%Y-%m'):
    d = pd.to_datetime(s, format=format)
    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(0, d.daysinmonth-1, periods), 
                          unit='D', origin=d)
```

Demo:

```
In [21]: random_dt('2017-10', 4)
Out[21]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-10-05', '2017-10-01', '2017-10-28', '2017-10-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [22]: random_dt('2017-Jan', periods=3, format='%Y-%b')
Out[22]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-14', '2017-01-09', '2017-01-25'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a random variable, for instance

```
import random
random_number = random.randint(0, 31)
```

this will make the variable random_number a random integer between 0 and 31